# How to reproduce a lost Session in asp.net/c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that sometimes my session gets lost randomly, whereas sometimes it works.

Now the question is, if it is somehow possible to reproduce the session (my session is the current logged in user). I thought maybe I need to change something in my master page where I'm right now just checking if the session is failed, something with the else?

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserId"] == null)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Write("Not agine");
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write(Session["UserId"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
  void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User is HtUser)
        {

            HtUser user = (HtUser)HttpContext.Current.User;
            Session["UserId"] = user.UserId;
            if (user.HtDepartments.Any() && user.HtDepartments.SingleOrDefault().HtBusinessUnit != null)
            {
                int BusinessUnitId = user.HtDepartments.First().HtBusinessUnit.BusinessUnitId;
                Session["BusinessUnnitId"] = BusinessUnitId;
            }
```

here you can see the code for the session

If you need something more just let me know!

Thanks for help and fast answer!

Comment: What do you mean by reproduce the session?

Comment: @nunespascal if the session is lost I want to give the aktuell logged in user back as the session

Comment: Do you know what's causing you to lose the session; i.e. is it a timeout, are you working with multiple servers (e.g. the session's created on server A but the next request goes to server B), are you using the querystring to identify sessions and thus you lose reference to the session if the querystring is cleared, or something else?

Comment: Did you try and out-of-proc session?

Comment: @Mingebag Sessions are not usually lost, they do timeout and get destroyed. You can't give them back to the user if they don't exist.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I really dont know why I'm loosing the session maybe ie but i really dont know ... if updated my code in the top and no and using on server

Comment: @Steve thanks for your advice but i have a question can you give me some more infos for the 1 solution . the second one is wrong .. and yee I'm already trying to find a solution for this problem for more then tow days ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understand right, user loosing session when it's expired (timed out).

To prevent this you can store additional keys in cookies (for i.e. user_id and unique_hash per user), then write a method in global.asax file which will fire every page load, and check if session is expired. If so, method will restore session using cookies keys by checking them against DB.

Example code in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        // Restore session if session is lost but cookie is not
        // HttpContext.Current.Session["user_id"] == null &&
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["hash"] != null)
        {
            // do your job here
            RestoreSessionMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have maybe some example ?

Comment: basically i'm using approach above to revert session even after browser tab was closed, so user don't need to login everytime. please mark as answer or vote if it's helps. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Session.Abandon` method

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your session state in memory, and not in SQL Server for example, you can open your page do operations that store data in session and then leave your browser open and change your web.config file or from command line do iisreset.exe.

This will flush your session state data from memory and you will simulate the lost of the session state.

Comment: I never heard how to keep a session in SQL server you have maybe a example for your solution ?

Comment: I didn't say that you should do it, just mentioned it as a possibility. You can read more about it here: HOW TO: Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604